# Manipulating double summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

In a problem in my book, the following equality is there:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big( \sum_{k_i\ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^\infty ik_i=n}\frac{x^n}{\prod_{i=1}^\infty k_i!(i!)^{k_i}}\Big)=\sum_{k_i\ge 0}\Big(\frac{x^{\sum_{i=1}^\infty ik_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^\infty k_i!(i!)^{k_i}}\Big)$$

where the summation runs over all sequences $k_1,k_2\cdots$ of non-negative integers containing finitely many non-zero entries. It is not clear to me how to this equality is obtained. I did work out something like $\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^jf(j,k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=k}^\infty f(j,k)$ but I cannot get it to to apply here.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The expression on the RHS is weird (the power of $x$). You have something like $x^{i=1}$. What does that notation mean?

Comment: @LordSoth :For a fixed $(k_1,\cdots, k_t), k_j\ne 0$ it means $x^{k_1+2k_2+\cdots tk_t=n}$. The overall sum runs over all choices of $k_1,k_2,\cdots$ with finitely many non-zero entries.

Comment: No I get that one, but what does e.g. $x^{i=1}$ mean? Is it $x^1$ if $i=1$, and $x^0$ if $i \neq 0$?

Comment: @LordSoth: Sorry, that was a mistake. I am correcting it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{K} = \{(k_1,k_2,\ldots):k_i\geq 0,\,k_i \in \mathbb{Z}_+,\mbox{finitely many }k_i\mbox{ are non-zero}\}$. You may then write $\mathcal{K}$ as a countable union of disjoint sets as $\mathcal{K} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{K}_n$, where $\mathcal{K}_n =  \{(k_1,k_2,\ldots):k_i\geq 0,\,k_i \in \mathbb{Z}_+,\,\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ik_i = n\}$ (The fact that there are finitely many non-zero $k_i$ allows you to have this decomposition). Therefore, for any (converging etc) function $f(\mathbf{k})$ with $\mathbf{k}\in\mathcal{K}$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in\mathcal{K}}f(\mathbf{k}) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in\mathcal{K}_n}f(\mathbf{k}) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{k_i\geq 0,\,\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ik_i = n}f(\mathbf{k})
\end{align}