# Can we formally multiply out infinite products?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product, absolute-convergence

I came across Euler's proof that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. One of the ingredients of the proof uses
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)=1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}+\text{higher order powers}$$
i.e. it **seems** that we can treat an infinite product as a finite product in the sense that we can "multiply it out and collect like powers". How can this be justified? If it cannot be justified, can you give a counterexample?

Assume that the infinite product converges absolutely.

Comment: Multiplying infinitely many infinite products is essentially the same as summing infinitely many infinite series (by taking $\log$) so generally is done specifying a way - eg you multiply finitely many in a given order say $P_1..P_n$ and take the limit $n\to\infty$ or take a net limit on all finite subsets of the index set; for good products all these ways are same at the end; also you have to be careful how you define absolute convergent products  btw

Comment: @Conrad Does this imply that we can collect like powers? Why?

Comment: Let $(a_j)_{j \in X}$ indexed by a set $X$, $F(X)$ the set of finite subsets of $X$ with the inclusion order; this is a net so we define $\sum_{j \in X}a_j=\lim_{J \in F(X)} \sum_{j \in J}a_j$ if it exists; it's not hard to prove that happens iff $\sup_{J \in F(X)}\sum_{j \in J}|a_j| < \infty$ and then we can rearrange $\sum_{j \in X}a_j$ in any way we want; take $X$ the set of all $k$ possible products (all $k \ge 1$) of the $a_{nm}$ when each infinite product is $P_{m}=\Pi_{n}(1+a_{mn})$ and the condition of absolute convergence is $\sum_n |a_{mn}|=M_m<\infty$ and then $\sum M_m <\infty$

Comment: then if the above depends (analytically) on a variable $x$ in the sense that $a_{mn}(x)$ are analytic and the absolute convergence above is uniform in $x$ at least on compacts, the result is analytic and we can expand it in power series, differentitate term by term etc, so, in particular, collecting like powers represents precisely the Taylor series of the final product

Comment: @Conrad If I understand correctly: the fact that the infinite product is analytic (suppose it is) implies that we can collect like powers?

Comment: @Conrad I know that analyticity implies that it has *some* power series representation, but why is it the one which is obtained by "multiplying out"?

Comment: correct - but the existence of such requires in general absolute convergence of a kind or another, locally uniform in a way or another and a correct definition so it satisfies the usual properties - as noted it turns out that such a defintion is in general possible only for absolutely convergent cases as conditional convergence is very order specific so it makes sense only for ordered indices

Comment: power series is unique (again in a case like above where we have absolute convergence); the best way to think of the final result is that it is the sum of all possible finite subproducts; so for example the coefficient of $x^2$ appears precisely only when one term is multiplied since two terms give $x^4$ etc (here we mean of course the $a_m(x)$ in $\Pi_n(1+a_m(x))$)

Comment: @Conrad But why is that unique power series obtained by multiplying out and collecting like powers? Why not some other way?

Comment: you can obtain any way you want that makes sense (again given absolute convergence) so in particular this is one way; by unicity any other way gives you this

Comment: not really sure what is the confusion here - thinking of the set $X$ of all $k \ge 0$ subproducts (so if you want $X={0} \cup \mathbb N \cup \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \cup...$ where we call $X_k$ the $k$ product, then for any $j \in X$, there is $k$ st $j=(m_1,..m_k)$, so defining $c_j(x)=a_{m_1}(x)...a_{m_k}(x)$  (here $c_0=1$ for the unique product of order $0$ of course) then the infinite product is absolutely convergent and is precisely $\sum_{j \in X} c_j$ as above; you can rearrange it this in any way so it is, for example, $\sum_{k \ge 0}(\sum_{j \in X_k}c_j)$ which is the power series

Comment: @Conrad According to the Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem, we "are allowed" to collect all the $x^2$ terms because of Newton's identities. It doesn't make sense to me, how exactly are Newton's identities used here?

Comment: taking Wikipedia at face value is not always a good idea- as a guide yes, but not as truth; so this being said, I have no idea what they mean by that as the proof I sketched above is straightforward

Comment: @Conrad Oh, alright. Thank you very much for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that many infinite products in Euler have some properties of finite products is explained in [this publication](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/infinitesimals.html#17b) in *Journal for General Philosophy of Science*.  Briefly, Euler's procedures can be formalized in a hyperreal extension of $\mathbb R$ where unlimited integers (greater than every standard integer) are available.  Infinite products are often approximated infinitely well by hyperfinite products.  The latter have all the first-order properties of ordinary finite products.  The article linked above analyzes in detail Euler's proof of the infinite product decomposition for the sine function.

Comment: Can a proof be carried out in the realm of standard analysis?

Comment: @Nomas2, of course :-)  The novelty is that even Euler's proof, that has been traditionally considered obscure, is justifiable in terms of modern theories of infinitesimals.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}$
[This is something I wrote in 2005. I've translated it from $\LaTeX{}$ to MathJax, and offer it for what it's worth.
I would have to revise quite a lot of stuff to make sure I still
understand it fully myself, but it's probably valid.
I never finished working on it, because I intended to go on to use
Möbius inversion to develop a theory that would generalise the relation between the terms and partial sums of an infinite series,
but I never got round to it.]

[In 2015, I came across a relevant Maths.SE answer, which for all I know may be more helpful than my own:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/509318/213690.]

**Lemma A.**
If the unordered sum $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ exists and equals
$\alpha$, then given any positive $\varepsilon$, there is a finite
subset $E$ of $X$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:inf_sub}\tag{1}
\abs{ \sum_{x \in Y} f(x) - \alpha } < \varepsilon 
\end{equation}
whenever $Y$ is a subset of $X$ and $Y \supset E$.
[Footnote: I think this could also be expressed by saying that the
function  $Y \mapsto \sum_{x \in Y} f(x)$ is *continuous* on
the directed set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of *all* subsets of $X$.]

*Proof.*
By the definition of unordered sum, there exists finite
$E \subset X$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:fin_sub}\tag{2}
\abs{ \sum_{x \in F} f(x) - \alpha } < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} 
\end{equation}
whenever $F$ is finite and $E \subset F \subset X$.

Suppose now $E \subset Y \subset X$, $Y$ not necessarily
finite.  $\sum_{x \in Y} f(x)$ is the limit of $\sum_{x \in F} 
f(x)$ for finite $F$ contained between $E$ and $Y$, so there
exists finite $G$ such that $E \subset G \subset Y$ and, if
$F$ is finite and $G \subset F \subset Y$, then
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:fin_inf}\tag{3}
\abs{ \sum_{x \in F} f(x) - \sum_{x \in Y} f(x) } < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
\end{equation}
Taking \eqref{eqn:fin_sub} and \eqref{eqn:fin_inf} together
(for an arbitrary choice of such $F$, for instance $F = G$)
gives \eqref{eqn:inf_sub}. $\ \square$

**Lemma B.**
Suppose that the unordered sum $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$
exists and equals $\alpha$.  Suppose also that $Y_1, Y_2, 
\dotsc$ is a sequence of  subsets of $X$ such that
$$ Y_1 \subset Y_2 \subset Y_3 \subset \dotsb, \quad
\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty Y_n = X. $$
Then
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:lim_sum}\tag{4}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x \in Y_n} f(x) 
\end{equation}
exists and equals $\alpha$.  In particular, if $Z_1, Z_2, 
\dotsc$ satisfies the same properties as the $Y_n$, then
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:lim_sum_eql}\tag{5}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{x \in Y_n} f(x) \right) =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{x \in Z_n} f(x) \right).
\end{equation}

*Proof.*
The same as Beardon, Theorem 5.2.2, but using
his Corollary 5.2.4, and Lemma A
above in place of the definition of unordered sum. $\ \square$

**Lemma C.**
Let $(a_{i, j})_{i \geqslant 1, j \geqslant 0}$ be a double sequence
of complex numbers such that $a_{i, 0} = 1$ and the series
$\sum_{j \geqslant 0} a_{i, j}$ converges absolutely for each
$i \geqslant 1$, and the infinite product $\prod_{i \geqslant 1} 
\sum_{j \geqslant 0} \abs{a_{i, j}}$ converges
[Apostol, section 8.26].
Let $\Lambda$ be the countable set consisting of all sequences
$\lambda = (\lambda_i)_{i \geqslant 1}$ of non-negative integers
almost all equal to 0, and define $d_\lambda =
\prod_{i \geqslant 1} a_{i, \lambda_i}$.  Then the family
$(d_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$
is absolutely summable [Dieudonné, section 5.3],
and if $b_i = \sum_{j \geqslant 0} a_{i, j}$ ($i \geqslant 1$),
the infinite product $\prod_{i \geqslant 1} b_i$ converges
to the unordered sum $\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} d_\lambda$
(or diverges to zero if the unordered sum is zero).  That is,
$$ \prod_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_{i, j} 
= \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \prod_{i = 1}^\infty a_{i, \lambda_i}. $$

*Proof.*
For $n \geqslant 1$, let $Y_n = \{ \lambda \in \Lambda :
\lambda_i = 0 \text{ for all } i > n \}$.  Then $Y_1 \subset
Y_2 \subset \dotsb$, and $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty Y_n = \Lambda$.
Also for $m \geqslant 0$, let $E_{mn} = \{ \lambda \in \Lambda 
: \lambda_i \leqslant m \text{ for } i = 1, \dotsc, n \}$.
Then $E_{mn}$ is finite, and $\bigcup_{m = 0}^\infty E_{mn} = Y_n$.

If $A$ is any finite subset of $\Lambda$, then $A \subset E_{mn}$
for some $(m, n)$, and then
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\lambda \in A} \abs{d_\lambda} 
 \leqslant \sum_{\lambda \in E_{mn}} \abs{d_\lambda}  
 = \prod_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 0}^m \abs{a_{ij}}  
 \leqslant \prod_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \abs{a_{ij}}  
 \leqslant \prod_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \abs{a_{ij}}  
\end{equation*}
so the unordered sum $\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} d_\lambda$
exists, by Beardon, Theorem 5.2.3(iii).

By Beardon, Theorem 5.2.2 (or the more general
Lemma B above), for $n \geqslant 1$,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\lambda \in Y_n} d_\lambda = 
\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{\lambda \in E_{mn}} d_\lambda = 
\lim_{m \to \infty} \prod_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 0}^m a_{ij}  = 
\prod_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_{ij}.
\end{equation*}

Therefore, by Lemma B,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} d_\lambda = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{\lambda \in Y_n} d_\lambda =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_{ij} =
\prod_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_{ij}. \quad \square
\end{equation*}

I note in passing that if, for $\lambda, \mu \in \Lambda$, we
define $\mu \leqslant \lambda$ iff $\mu_i \leqslant \lambda_i$ for
all $i \geqslant 1$, then the set $\Lambda$ itself is directed,
each set $\{ \mu : \mu \leqslant \lambda \}$ is finite, and
$$ \sum_{\mu \leqslant \lambda} d_\mu = 
\prod_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 0}^{\lambda_i} a_{ij} $$
(which despite apperances is a finite expression, on both sides).
One could prove a more general version of
Beardon, Theorem 5.2.2, in which the sequence
$(E_n)$ is replaced by a net (which in this instance happens
to be indexed by the set $\Lambda$ itself), so that we would have
$$ \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} d_\lambda = 
\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \sum_{\mu \leqslant \lambda} d_\mu $$
I wouldn't be surprised if this is part of some general
theory which I haven't had time to examine.  In any case, it
probably leads to a more elegant proof using the finite sets
$\{ \mu : \mu \leqslant \lambda \}$ instead of the $E_{mn}$
and $Y_n$.

Alternatively (and less elegantly), it might have been
possible to make do with the sets $E_{nn}$, but I didn't
even seriously consider this, as both of the other
possibilities seemed more natural.

**References**

Tom M. Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis*, 2nd edition (1974).

Alan F. Beardon, *Limits: A New Approach to Real Analysis* (1997).

J. Dieudonné, *Foundations of Modern Analysis* (1969).

Answer (score -2):

Suppose that you write instead $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{a_n^2\,\pi^2}\right)$$ Expand it as a Taylor series to obtain
$$1-\frac {x^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{a_n^2}+O(x^4)$$ Just let $a_n=n$.

The next term to $O(x^8)$ would be
$$+\frac {x^4}{\pi^4}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac 1{a_m^2\, a_n^2}$$ Now, is strats to be more difficult.

Comment: I don't understand how is this supposed to answer the question